# Perl: How is it possible that this code is working?

Tags: perl, hash, scalar

```
my %hash = ('red' => "John", 'blue' => "Smith"); 
func (%hash);  

sub func {
    my $hash = $_[0];
    print "$hash{'red'}\n";
    print "$hash{'blue'}\n";
}
```

I send a hash to a subroutine, and this hash is treated as scalar. If so, how is it possible that I can turn to a value in the hash by calling its key?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
func(%hash);
```

is equivalent to

```
func('red', 'John', 'blue', 'Smith'); 
   -or-
func('blue', 'Smith', 'red', 'John');
```

so

```
my $hash = $_[0];
```

is equivalent to

```
my $hash = 'red';
   -or-
my $hash = 'blue';
```

Totally useless. Good thing you never use `$hash` ever again.

---

Instead, you use the `%hash` declared outside the sub. You can see this by reordering your code or by limiting the scope (visibility) of `%hash`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    my %hash = ('red' => "John", 'blue' => "Smith"); 
    func(%hash);  
}

sub func {
    my $hash = $_[0];
    print "$hash{'red'}\n";
    print "$hash{'blue'}\n";
}
```

```
$ perl a.pl
Global symbol "%hash" requires explicit package name at a.pl line 11.
Global symbol "%hash" requires explicit package name at a.pl line 12.
Execution of a.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

---

The solution is to pass a reference.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
    my %hash = ('red' => "John", 'blue' => "Smith"); 
    func(\%hash);
}

sub func {
    my $hash = $_[0];
    print "$hash->{'red'}\n";
    print "$hash->{'blue'}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the scope of your `%hash` is the entire program.

Comment: why? it's declared with my. It's supposed to be local. no?

Comment: Might help to explain that `my $hash = $_[0];` and `print "$hash{'red'}\n";` are not referring to the same variable.

Comment: `my $x = '...'; if (...) { print $x }` works, therefore so does `my $x = '...'; sub foo { print $x }`.

Comment: Yes my %hash;   is local. But in this case local means the line where %hash is declared until the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

> %hash is supposed to be local. no?

It's local to the enclosing scope. Scopes are delimited by braces. But there are no braces anywhere surrounding your declaration:

```
my %hash;
```

As a result, `%hash` is visible inside every nested scope in the file. Here is an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;

my $str = "hello";

if (1) { #new scope starts here
    say "if: $str";
} #scope ends here

{ #new scope starts here

    my $planet = "world";
    say "block: $str";

    for (1..2) { #new scope starts here
        say "for: $str $planet";
    } #scope ends here

} #scope ends here

#say $planet;  #The $planet that was previously declared isn't visible here, so this looks
               #like  you are trying to print a global variable, which results in a
               #compile error, because global variables are illegal with: use strict;


--output:--
if: hello
block: hello
for: hello world
for: hello world
```